# Passing variable with POST in django

Tags: python, html, django

Hi im trying to pass a name from a form to a view in django using POST. There are no errors in the execution but its passing nothing from the template and dont know if i doing something wrong here. Im starting with django so i can have newbie errors. If u need more information tell me pls.

**Views.py**

```
def crear_pdf(request):
    empresa_selec = ""
    form = EmpModelForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = EmpModelForm(data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            empresa_selec = form.cleaned_data['nombre']

   #"empresa_selec" that's the empty variable
```

**Models.py**

```
class Empresa_modelo(models.Model):
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=True,null=True)
```

**Forms.py**

```
    class EmpModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
        class Meta:
            model = Empresa_modelo
            fields = ["nombre"]
```

**template.html**

```
 <div class="container-fluid">
            <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="{% url 'crear_pdf' %}">{% csrf_token %}
                <p>Empresa</p>
                <input type="text" name="empresa">
                <br>
                <button type="submit">Subir</button>
            </form>
            <br>
            <a class="btn btn-primary" href="{% url 'crear_pdf' %}">Atras</a>
        </div>
```

Comment: can you show the url rule for `crear_pdf` view?

Comment: You are not actually using your form in the template here. Try to follow the tutorial in the docs. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/forms/#the-view

Comment: You're not doing anything in your view function when the form data is invalid. To figure out what's going wrong you can add something like this after the `.is_valid()` block: `else: print('invalid data', request.POST)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using:

```
<input type="text" name="nombre">
```

There is no field named empresa.

Answer (score 2):

You haven't got a field called `nombre` in your template; you only have `empresa`.

That's presumably because you don't ouput your EmpModelForm in the template. You don't show your `render` call in the view, but assuming you pass it as `form`, you should just do `{{ form.as_p }}` in the template.

Comment: Oh that's true, thank you for the answer help me a lot!!

Answer (score 1):

Had a look at your code,there are a couple of issues.First you are not using the model form defined in your forms.py file in your template. Second you have defined an input text box with the name that you are not referring in your views. Either use the model form or use the same name of your input text box in your views.

```
def crear_pdf(request):
empresa_selec = ""
form = EmpModelForm()
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = EmpModelForm(data=request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        empresa_selec = form.cleaned_data['nombre']
else:
    return render(request,"template.html",{"form":form})
```

And in your template you can edit as such:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
        <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="{% url 'crear_pdf' %}">{% csrf_token %}
            {{ form.as_p }}
            <br>
            <button type="submit">Subir</button>
        </form>
        <br>
        <a class="btn btn-primary" href="{% url 'crear_pdf' %}">Atras</a>
    </div>
```

Hope this helps.